# getline() skipping the first two characters in from my CSV file in c++

Tags: c++, csv

My code is supposed to read math problems from a CSV file and then check if they are answered correctly, but whenever I use the `getline()` it just doesn't get the first two characters from each line.
(also ignore the comments those are from the base file I had to use)

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    fstream fin;
    int comma;
    float cans, sans, question, correct;
    fin.open("problems.csv");
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cerr << "File cannot be opened for reading." << endl;
        exit(1); // exit if failed to open the file
    }
    vector<string> row;        // new string variable
    string line, word, temp, problem; 
    correct = 0;
    question = 0;
    while(fin >> temp) { 
        question ++;
        row.clear();
        // this loop reads the file line-by-line
        // extracting 5 values on each iteration
        getline(fin, line);
        comma = line.find(",");
        cans = stod(line.substr(comma + 1));
        cout << "(" << question << ") " << line.substr(0,comma) << "? ";
        cin >> sans;
        if (sans == cans){
            cout << "true" << endl;
            correct ++;
        } else {
            cout << "false" << endl;
        }
        fin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); //skips to the end of line, 
                            //ignorring the remaining columns 
    
        // for example, to print the date and East basin storage:
        //cout << date << " " << eastSt << endl;
    }
}
```

csv file:

[image: my csv file]

code output:

[image: my code output]

I tried using `temp` instead of `line`, but then my conversion to `int`s didn't work.

Comment: Why are you doing `fin >> temp`?  That's almost certainly how you're losing characters.

Comment: Research `std::stringstream`.  It will allow you to treat the string you read as a stream.

Comment: You read the first word from `fin` into `temp` and then you do nothing with the first word read. Your code gets the first two characters into `tmp` and then does nothing with them.

Comment: Don't post pictures of texts, instead post texts in code blocks.

Comment: `std::getline` gets the **rest of** the line. After `std::cin >> temp`, the rest of the line doesn't have the first couple of characters, because they're in `temp`.

Comment: Side note: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `std::fstream fin; ... fin.open("problems.csv");` to `std::fstream fin("problems.csv");`.

Comment: Another side note: nothing in this program needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, you are reading the first few characters of each line into `temp` and then you ignore it.

You need to replace this:

`while(fin >> temp)`

with this instead:

`while (getline(fin, line))`

and then you can parse `line` as needed.